# ASP.NET DB2 leading zero in where clause

Tags: sql, asp.net, db2

I am trying to retrieve records but when there is a leading zero in the where clause, it returns no records. The field in the database is not a numeric field.

```
>txtInput.Text = '035453' // from console

SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE field = txtInput.Text
```

How do I retrieve records with a leading zero in the where clause? There are records but they are not returned.

Comment: show us the data you want to retrieve

Comment: why would someone down vote? the question is clear.

Comment: what is the type of 'field' ? integer ?varchar?

Comment: the field is varchar but for some reason it will not retrieve records if the beginning of the where clause starts with a leading zero. I have looked in the debug and have seen that the correct string is being passed to the DB. When the records are retrieved through the AS400 interface, it works. However, through the intranet it doesn't work.

Comment: How are you executing this SQL?  Unless you are using parameter markers, you'll need to put single quotes around your string value.  `... where field = 'txtInput.Text'`.  This may require building the SQL statement as a string (so you can substitute the value of `txtInput.Text` and then executing it.